# Angular2 rc.5 and hashbang

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, hashbang

In previous rc.4 release setting up hashbang #! looked like this

```
bootstrap(ApplicationComponent, [....
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '!'}
]);
```

Now in rc.5 everything got changed a litte bit and I struggle to find a way to have same address containing #!

Angular docs are quite clear about setting up routing but hashbang is somewhat skipped in tha description(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) . Setting up hash alone is done like so in rc.5 app.routing.ts

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

however not sure how to additionally define "!" in url in rc.5

I am not sure how it should be applied and in what form. Perhaps in boostrap:... inside @NgModule in app.module but so far I did not make it work. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this in `app.module.ts` file by adding it in `providers` array

```
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Request, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
let http = injector.get(Http);
let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage(), http);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide:AuthService,useValue:authService}, // over here
    AdminAuthGuard,
    UserAuthGuard
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I already tried it but gave it one more shot and all is good. Thanks.